# PostgreSQL trigger parametrized by attribute name

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I want to create a trigger which will made selected attribute (given as a parameter) uppercase on first letter and lowercase on the remaining.

I would like to write it in similar way to this non-working code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myTrigger() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        colname TEXT;
        newContent TEXT;
    BEGIN
        colname = TG_ARGV[0];
        newContent = format('SELECT ( CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(NEW.%I,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(NEW.%I,2,LENGTH(NEW.%I)))) )', colname, colname, colname);
        EXECUTE newContent INTO format('NEW.%I', colname);
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

Why isn't it possible to `EXECUTE` prepared statement inside of the trigger just like in the console?

Comment: Define "*non-working*"? What is the error message you get? What is the `create trigger` statement?

Comment: In `INTO format(...)` format is not a variable. Trigger statement is
`CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE myTrigger('sname');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically update the NEW variable (this means, with the attribute name as variable) you can first build a hstore variable based on NEW, manipulate the hstore variable as you need and finally update the NEW variable with the [populate_record function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myTrigger() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        colname TEXT;
        newContent TEXT;
        new_record hstore;
BEGIN
colname = TG_ARGV[0];

    -- build a hstore from the NEW variable
    new_record= hstore(NEW);

    --fetch new content from hstore
    newContent = new_record -> colname;
    --updating the value
    newContent =  CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(newContent,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(newContent,2,LENGTH(newContent)))) ;
    -- updating hstore content with new value
    new_record = new_record || hstore(colname , newContent);
    --updating the NEW variable with the populate_record function
    NEW = populate_record(NEW,new_record );
    RETURN  NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```